# Hide table when number of child rows is below certain count

Tags: jquery

I have a page with 10 php/mysql generated tables.
All the tables have the same ID.

The number of rows is different. When the rowcount of one of the tables is smaller then 3, I would like to hide the complete table.

How can I loop through the tables and hide the specific table(s). With the use of jQuery?

Comment: Excuse me but All the tables have the same ID or 'class'?

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All the tables have the same ID.

IDs must be unique.  Use classes instead.

To answer your question: Hide all tables that don't have a visible third row, noting that `eq()` is zero-based:

```js
$('table:not(:has(tr:visible:eq(2)))').hide();
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>Hidden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hidden</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>Hidden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hidden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hidden</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr class="hidden"><td>Hidden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Visible</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Visible</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Visible</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice. But I only want to count the visible rows. In a pre-action I hide a row

Comment: Yes. I first hide a row, then in the same action I would like to do a count of the visible rows and hide the complete table if number of rows > 2

Comment: You can use the `:visible` selector.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
if($("table tr").length < 10){
    $("table tr").addClass('display-none');
}
```

And the css is (or any other way to hide the table):

```
.display-none{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('table').each(function(){
    var row = $(this).find('tbody > tr').length;
    if(row<3){
       $(this).hide();
    } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>AA</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>CC</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>AA</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>BB</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```